# ir - Using document-term [Boolean] incidence matrix for answering a query

Tags: algorithms, information-retrieval

The book "Introduction to Information Retrieval" [talks about term-document incidence matrix](https://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/an-example-information-retrieval-problem-1.html) for retrieving documents that contain/not-contain certain tokens drawn from a query. This representation naturally lends itself to retrieving documents in response to a query.

However, considering the document-term [boolean] incidence matrix, wherein each document is a boolean-vector marking the tokens that do/don't occur in the document;

Q: **Is there a canonical way for retrieving documents using the document-term [Boolean] incidence matrix?**

***My thoughts***: consider the same sample query as used in the text, *Brutus `&` Caesar `&` ~Calpurnia*; the only possible solution I can see is as follows

- iterate over all the documents, and for each document:

  - only consider the bits corresponding to the tokens found in the query expression, i.e., in the for above samle-query would be *Brutus*, *Caesar*, and *Calpurnia*.
  - evaluate the query expression
  - consider the document only if the above-step evaluates to `1`

Comment: I don't know what "canonical" means in this context, but text databases typically perform a merge of the postings entries, similar to a sort-merge join in relational databases (except that they are already sorted into document order). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sort-merge_join

Comment: When dealing with an inverted-index, the "canonical"/the-most-common method for retrieving documents is merging the postings list. Similarly, is there a canonical method for retrieving documents using a forward-index?

Comment: In text databases, it's rare to use forward indexes to locate documents because it does, as you say, require iterating over all documents.